# Material UI/React errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I installed Material UI and I tried importing it into my React project. It showed " Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/core/Button "

How do I import it from node_modules ??

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
          </div>
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <Button variant ="contained" label = "Material UI" />
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i have posted my code...

Comment: Can you list the contents of your package.json file? It would help to know which versions of react and MUI you have installed currently.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
```

Try this.

Answer (score -1):

Install material ui with npm or yarn. This should be done from your project's main directory.

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

Then, you can use `import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';` at the top of your file.

Answer (score -1):

Since this post is quite recent, I am pretty sure you followed the steps in [material-ui getting started](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/).

What you should do is check the version of material-ui core installed in your project. Within your package.json file, check your material-ui core version, it should look like this,

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",
    "@date-io/moment": "0.0.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^3.0.0-alpha.23",
  }
```

or you can just do

> npm list

to check all dependencies you have within your project.

Find out the lastest and stable version they have on [npm material-ui/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core)